# How to Cast A Variable Using Generic Type Parameter and 'as' Operator

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have the following generic static class which is being used in a Fluent API. It takes an input parameter and returns a wrapper class containing the parameter cast to the generic type.:

```
public static Foo<TOut> InputAs<TOut>(object parameter) {

    var castParameter = parameter as TOut;

    if(castParameter == null) {
         throw new Exception("Invalid cast");
    }

    return new Foo<TOut>(castParameter);

}
```

The problem is that the `castParameter == null` check always returns `null`.  What would be the correct way to cast the object using the `TOut` generic parameter as the new type?

Comment: Why not: `public static Foo<TOut> InputAs<TOut>(TOut parameter) {` ? Like that you can enforce the input parameter to be of the expected type. If you need a base class you can extend it with restrictions: `public static Foo<TOut> InputAs<TOut>(TOut parameter) where TOut : ISomeInterface {`

Answer (score 0):

Well, if `parameter as TOut` returns `null`, then the runtime type of `parameter` isn't `TOut`.

Don't forget that operator resolution is done at compile-time, so if you have cast operators defined, they will *not* be invoked here. If you do need that, you can use `dynamic`:

```
public static Foo<TOut> InputAs<TOut>(dynamic parameter) 
{    
    return new Foo<TOut>((TOut)parameter);
}
```

This will allow runtime operator resolution, and will call your cast operator if one is available. For example, it will allow you to pass `long`, while expecting `int`.

However, you probably want to find a different way of what you're trying to do; `dynamic` can be very useful, but it can also make debugging quite a bit harder, and you lose almost all compile-time warnings and errors that can help you identify problems before they happen.